# sorting one list and then sorting another based on the first

Tags: python, sorting

I have two lists `ns` and `ts`. I would like to sort `ns` and then, based on the way it was sorted, move around `ts` so that it matches `ns` accordingly. Something like this would be the input and output:

```
ns = (0 4 2 5 1)
ts = (1 2 3 4 5)

ns = (0 1 2 4 5)
ts = (1 5 3 2 4)
```

I know that I can sort each of these via `ns.sort()` and `ts.sort()`, but this will only help to sort `ns`.

Comment: What do you mean by the way it was sorted? Also, there is no `5` in your output for `ts`, why?

Comment: because I am bad at typing =)

Answer (score 1):

You could sort the two lists zipped together:

```
In [5]: sorted(zip(ns, ts))
Out[5]: [(0, 1), (1, 5), (2, 3), (4, 2), (5, 4)]
```

And then grab the second element in the tuples:

```
In [6]: [pair[1] for pair in sorted(zip(ns, ts))]
Out[6]: [1, 5, 3, 2, 4]
```

Or less readable:

```
zip(*sorted(zip(ns, ts)))[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip, sort, unzip, unpack:

```
ns = (0, 4, 2, 5, 1)
ts = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
ns, ts = zip(*sorted(zip(ns, ts)))
```